# String split by dot - Java

Tags: java, string

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "21.12.2015";
    String delim = "\\.";
    String[] st = str.split(delim);
    System.out.println(st[0]+"."+st[1]+"."+st[2]);        // 1
    System.out.println(st[0]+delim+st[1]+delim+st[2]);    // 2
}
```

Now, line 1 is printing expected output - 21.12.2015. But why line 2 is not giving same output as line 1? Why it is printing like 21\.12\.2015?

**EDIT:**

Actually in my requirement, the delimiter changes dynamically for each string(- or / or .). So I am trying to assign the delimiter to a variable and then split by it and finally print it as a pattern(say dd.mm.yy or dd-mm-yy or etc). For other delimiters it's fine, but for dot it's coming like dd\.mm\.yy. How shall I achieve the expected result?

Comment: Is `delim`s assigned value `"\\."` the same as "."? No. Then they can't result in the same output, right?

Comment: OP used "\\." because `split(String regex)` takes a REGEXP string param, so OP escaped the dot which is a REGEXP.

Comment: why not just split by '.'

Comment: @JClassic - You should try it.. You will probably understand why it is *wrong* :)

Comment: @JClassic...split by takes a regex. So, simply "." will be considered as any character(in terms of regex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This handles all delim values:

```
String str = "21.12.2015";
String delim = ".";   // or "-" or "?" or ...
String[] st = str.split(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(delim));
```

Comment: Ya.. `quote()` will do the Job. :)

Comment: It's coming correctly but another problem arises. I am using import jregex.Pattern; which is colliding with your import java.util.regex.Pattern; Any other solution adhering to jregex.Pattern; ?

Answer (score 1):

When you say split you are using `delim` as a regex pattern. It is treated differently. Please have a look to this [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

But when  you are using delim in sysout you are using it as string. the difference is obviuos

Answer (score 0):

When you create the `delim` variable, you escape the backslash. The real value of the `delim` variable is `\.`.
Just create the delim variable as (the backslash is useless):

```
String delim = ".";
```

Answer (score 0):

because of  `delim  = "\\."`, while spliting `"\\."` is required.

Answer (score 0):

Split method uses regex for splitting so you will need to provide as `\\.` while this is not the scenario when you are printing it, you just need to use '.' directly.

In Java `\\.` will be printed as `\.` as `\\` is considered as a single backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the split method from the String class, which uses regular expression for splitting the the string.

Due to this the \\. will split the string by every dot and needs to be escaped, since the dot itself is part of the regular expression.

In the second part you are simply printing the string, in which the backlash itself is a indicator for an string expression (like \n as a new line).

The double backlash just excludes this string expression to be written as a normal string "\n" in this case, and thats why you get the "\." result

For better understanding, try to delete one of the backslashes in the delim variable, and the java interpreter will throw an error since "\." is not a string expression

Answer (score 0):

`\\.` is a regex String to *parse* `.` *literally*. You need it while splitting (since `split()` expects a regex String).

While printing, you need to use `.` directly isntead of `"\\."` because `println()` doesn't need a regex.

Comment: "println doesn't need a regex": Thank Gosling&Steele for that ;-))

Comment: @laune - I think Java 9 will probably introduce a `println()` accepting a regex pattern :P